# Java Built-in Observer pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, observable

Regarding the observer built-in design pattern:

```
 java.util.Observable;
 java.util.Observer;
```

Does thet observation have to be serializable?

The `Observer` has a contract to implement an `update` method for callbacks on what its observing. The callback would look like this:

```
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, final Object observation) {
    // do some stuff with the notification
}
```

My question then is: the last parameter called observation, does it have to be serializable or can I notify on any kind of object?

Comment: It can be any kind of object, it is just an extra parameter. If all you are interested in is the observable object then the observation object could simply be null.

Comment: Where did you even get the idea that it may need to be serializeable from?

Comment: im researching in android how to transfer complex object across fragments, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there was a requirement for the object to be serializable, it would have been declared as such in the interface definition.  As in:

```
public void update(Observable observable, final Serializable observation)
```

but it is not, so there is no such requirement imposed.

Answer (score 2):

No, the `observation` parameter does not have to be serializable. Otherwise parameters type should be `Serializable`.